# Using List(Of T).ForEach method to update values not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, lambda, extension-methods, anonymous-methods

I have the following code,

```
PB.ForEach(Function(x) x.Cost = GetPartCost(x.PartNumber, x.Units, x.Cost, FB))

Return PB.Sum(Function(x) (x.Cost * x.Qty))
```

However it always returns 0. I've checked and the `GetPartCost` function executes and returns a non-zero number but the list item cost properties are never updated.

The property is just a simple property,

```
Public Property Cost() As Double
    Get
        Return _Cost
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        _Cost = value
    End Set
End Property
```

If I set a breakpoint in the `Set` of the property, it never gets hit.

What is going on with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is your confusing comparison with assignment.

```
Function(x) x.Cost = GetPartCost ...
```

This compiles down to a comparison between `x.Cost` and `GetPartCost` not an assignment.  The reason why is that `Function (x)` is an expression lambda and when used in the context of an expression `=` is comparison not assignment.

To fix this use a statement / `Sub` to produce assignment semantics

```
Sub(x) x.Cost = GetPartCost ...
```

Note: `Sub` lambdas aren't available until Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Ah, I had noticed that `Function` didn't make any sense in the context, but I didn't think about that darn VB `=` operator.